# Building a binary with native extensions - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmake, taglib

I am using a C++ taglib library needed by my application. I want to compile everything so it ships independently without having to search for extensions. externally.

Let's say I have a ruby/rails application that depends on a C++ library. How can I make my application independent by including all extensions in let's say the vendor directory?

I'm asking because when I deploy my application on Heroku I haven't been able to use C libraries in the application. Heroku has offered a way to build libraries using Vulcan but Vulcan uses AutoConf and I need CMAKE to build taglib.

[taglib-ruby-gem](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) depends on [TagLib](http://taglib.github.com)(C library) which needs [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/) to be built. How can I make this work natively?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it by myself but as per example [here](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan) you can provide command line to vulcan

You can try something like that

```
vulcan build -s <path to source code> -c "cmake . && make install"
```